# Equivalent of .Net Data Repeater in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, repeater

I'm a total noob to Xcode and Interface builder. I'm on version 3.2.3 and OSX 10.6.4.

What I'd like to know, and haven't been able to find out, is how to display a list of n items. Using .Net, I'd probably use a Data Repeater control and then use that to repeatedly populate the controls I'd like to display.

Is there an equivalent or am I going about things in the wrong way? I don't see anything in the IB controls library that is quite what I'm looking for.

Any help is much appreciated, even a direction to a relevant tutorial or something.

Regards,
Iain

Comment: Thanks for the answers, gave Eimantas the acceptance for the extra info, thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are looking for NSTableView with it's DataSource (ArrayController or equivalent) and it's delegate (for defining N items)?

Answer (score 1):

The most common view for displaying lists is NSTableView. There are many, many tutorials on the web... Just google 'nstableview tutorial' and take your pick. :-)